# Are uninsulated steam pipes behind walls and touching beams a fire hazard?

Tags: plumbing, heating, basement, boiler, steam

We are getting our unfinished basement done. We have replaced and rerouted (to make more space) our steam pipes (house built in 1937) with new pipes (Black and I believe 4 inches in diameter). These pipes run into/from the boiler and run very hot. We are getting sheetrock walls built in the basement to cover existing concrete walls and pipes will run behind the sheetrock.

Plumber says the pipes can remain behind the sheetrock walls to help generate heat and that the pipes don't need to be wrapped/insulated. He also says that the pipes can run against ceiling beams without being insulated.

Question: Is it safe to have these pipes behind walls or against (touching) wooden structural beams if the pipes will be non-insulated/wrapped? I am very concerned about potential fire risks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Do you know the temperature of steam pipes? Do you know the ignition point of wood?

Some say the "ignition" point of wood is 451 deg F. Most say around 570 deg F. Either way, the surface temperature of steam pipes will NEVER even get close to that. Typically upwards of 250 deg F. I think you can trust your plumber on this one.

Comment: 451 is paper's ignition point, at least according to the fire department Ray Bradbury called, or so the tale goes. Household steam is generally 15 PSI or 250 degrees F at the most.

Comment: (Note that this is asking about HOUSEHOLD steam. Industrial steam, under high pressure, can reach much higher temperature.)

Comment: @keshlam, this is the HOME improvement forum after all.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey: Absolutely. I'm not disagreeing (I upvoted your answer), just adding a footnote so folks know that your "NEVER" is true for this domain but may not be true elsewhere.)

Comment: Gotcha. I guess I should assume folks will incorrectly come to boards like this for commercial info. Then again, if they do it's their mistake, not ours.

Answer (score 0):

Your plumber is a fool for saying your steam mains and risers don't have to be insulated.

You want your steam to stay steam as it makes it's way to the radiators.  Uninsulated pipes means the steam will give up it's latent energy to the pipe and condense the steam back to water until the pipes are well heated.  This results in a much longer time for the steam to push the air out of the mains (and therefore much slower heating radiators) and most likely water hammer, that banging sound steam systems are notorious for, especially on cold days.

The Dead Men who designed steam systems always insulated the pipes and they knew what they were doing because back then steam systems were common.  Sounds like your plumber isn't very well versed in the art of what is now viewed as an antiquated way to heat the home.  Insulated pipes, fast venting mains and slow venting radiators are what you want.